# How do I remove the cistern lid that has been grouted in?

Tags: toilet, grout, tiling

My tiler grouted the cistern lid against the wall a few months back. Only realized when the toilet started leaking and I couldn't open it. What is the best way to get rid of the grout and try and release the cistern from the wall? I'm hoping there's no more cement behind the grout... [image][image]

Comment: Could you provide a photo your life type is different than the type normally used on this side of the pond I believe.

Comment: Call the tiler and point out the problem they caused, and request that they fix it, at their expense.

Comment: I'm guessing that there's a corresponding hole in the tile on the wall. Not good. That said, you should've had the tile removed for that job.

Answer (score 2):

Yikes. That was a really bad idea on his part.

The first thing I would try is a grout saw. It's designed to grind the grout out without damaging the tile. Hopefully grout is your only obstacle.

If the tiles immediately above the tank are insurmountable, your next job will be to try and remove them. They are partial tiles and hopefully you can remove them by sawing the grout out and prying them up (they will probably break in doing so). Once the tiles are out, hopefully that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using a nail set or narrow punch to tap the grout loose. This is the quick way to remove/break the grout joint. Keep punch centered on grout and use gentle soft hammer taps.

Most likely some of the lid is covered by grout so keep the punch at a shallow angle (20-30 degrees).

Once the grout is loosened try to lift the lid. If it can be moved even slightly keep working it until the grout crumbles.

It may be safer to use a section of wood cut to a blunt point as a chisel. This will not chip the porcelain as easily as a metal tool would.